# Forcing Android Fast Scroll Bar on ListViews to draw within padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am interested in creating a screen composed of a transparent header and a listview that scrolls behind the header.   I have this working with one flaw; the FAST scroll bar also draws underneath header.

For some reason, the fastscrollbar doesn't seem to respect the scrollbarStyle applied to the list view.   You'll notice in the image below that the normal scroll bar works fine, but the powerscroll bar is behind the transparent header.

[image: FastScrollBar and NormalScrollBar example]

Unfortunately the listviews I am using will often have hundreds of items, so the fastscrollbar is a necessity.  Is there some way to set the "fastscrollStyle" that is not documented?   I am open to any suggestions!   Thank you.

Here is the layout XML for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"/>

    <TextView android:text="My Header"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:background="#8fff0000"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This was fixed in KitKat for ListView, however GridView still appears to exhibit this problem.  Google?

Comment: Use linearlayout instead of relativelayout. The header on top, and set the listview position under the header. Listitems will never seen behind of the header and scrollbar icon, too.

Comment: I want the listview items to draw behind the header while also having the fast scrollbar respect the listview's vertical padding.  Linearlayout doesn't have a fast scroll and will have very poor performance if you added thousands items to it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to separate your listview from the other layouts, where the main relativelayout view is the parent and other layouts are the children.

EX.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <RelativeLayout
              android:id"@+id/layoutHeader"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

              <TextView android:text="My Header"
                        android:gravity="center"
                       android:background="#8fff0000"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="+id/layoutHeader">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't this simply draw the listview in front of the header while creating an unnecessarily larger view hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

This bug appears to be fixed in 4.4.   In older versions however, there appears to be no known workaround other than leaving padding at 0.